# Laravel multiple relationships with calculations

Tags: laravel

Trying to substraction beyween two relationship results.
But couldn't think, how it can be possible.

```
$customer_index = Customer::where('firm_id', $firm_id)
    ->withCount(['orders as orders_total' => function($q){
        $q->select(DB::raw("SUM(total-discount) as paidsum"));
        $q->where('status', 1);
    },
    'receipts as receipts_total' => function($q){
        $q->select(DB::raw("SUM(price) as paidsum"));
    }])
    ->select('*', '(orders_total-receipts_total) as result')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
```

It doesn't work of course.
But how can be possible to work?
I need to calculate; orders total. and calculate receipts total, and make substraction betweek them. And return this as a column in my json response.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. I see you have `customers` and `customers` have many `orders` right? Then it looks like you have `receipts` are these records of payments against orders? And `discounts` is a `discount` an item of credit against an account? Are you trying to calculate the total price of a `customer`'s `orders` minus any `discounts` minus any `payments` already made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```php
$results = Customer::where('firm_id', $firm_id)
    ->with([
        'orders' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 1);
        },
        'receipts'
    ])
    ->latest('id')
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($customer) {
        $customer->orders_total = $customer->orders->sum->total - $customer->orders->sum->discount;
        $customer->receipts_total = $customer->receipts->sum->price;
        $customer->result = $customer->orders_total - $customer->receipts_total;
    });
```